# How to get the to the average in the Ventura-Martinez version of Grover search?

Tags: grovers-algorithm

Apparently there is an improved version of the Grover algorithm named after Ventura, Martinez from the paper [Quantum Associative Memory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9807053.pdf). The trick (and the step I wouldn't know how to implement) is to perform 1 iteration of regular Grover, and after that, rotate all amplitudes by the average.

So the question is: how to get to the average, say, with a circuit? I can compute it by looking at the state vector, but how does that translate to a physical system?

Comment: I would recommend to ask one question at time. Try to change your question for example to simple *Is there an resource where the algorithm is actually implemented as I would like to see how the circuit looks like?*

Comment: I suggest to look at the following paper: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-02866-z for discussion of the work by Ventura and Martinez and an implementation of a quantum associative memory in a format compatible with quantum gate-based circuits utilized in IBMQ.